# can't find valid maven repository for hibernate-search-4.2.0.Final.jar

Tags: maven, jar, hibernate-search

I use maven.

I want to use the last version of hibernate-search : 4.2.0.Final
I was under 3.3.0.Final

I can't a valid maven repository for this version.

Which maven repository I have to use to get this version of hibernate search ?

Because if you go there : 
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.hibernate~hibernate-search~~~~kw,versionexpand

You'll find the version I need, but when I download hibernate-search-4.2.0.Final.jar and I unarchive it, I see there is only META-INF folder but no class in the jar : the jar is invalid !

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hibernate-search project changed their artifact structure to use hibernate-search-orm instead of hibernate-search.  Hibernate-search is now just a jar that declares a dependency on hibernate-search-orm which maven will resolve transitively and include in your project.

See the upgrade notes here - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide

More specifically this note - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide#New_jars_Maven_modules_reorganization

If you look in the pom for hibernate search you will see the dependency - this should all be resolved from central without any additional repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best repository for JBoss artifacts is: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/

The available repositories are explained in their wiki: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository

The group `public-jboss` contains all releases and third-party artifacts required to by JBoss artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't maven central good enough ?

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|hibernate-search

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a JBoss project, you can get newest builds from our [Nexus](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#welcome) repository. [Here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Developers) is how to configure it in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`. Your `pom.xml` then should contain this dependecy.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Upvoted as it's correct and useful, but Hibernate Search is distributed on Maven central too!